# How can I find out whether a field in a dataclass has the default value or whether it's explicitly set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a `dataclass` for which I'd like to find out whether each field was explicitly set or whether it was populated by either `default` or `default_factory`.

I know that I can get all fields using `dataclasses.fields(...)` and that'll probably work for fields that use `default` but not easily for fields using `default_factory`.

My end goal is to merge two dataclass instances *A* and *B*. While *B* should only override fields of *A* where *A* is using the default value.

The use case is a configuration object that can be specified in multiple *locations* and some have a higher priority than others.

Edit: An example

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

def bar():
  return "bar"

@dataclass
class Configuration:
  foo: str = field(default_factory=bar)

conf1 = Configuration(
)

conf2 = Configuration(
  foo="foo"
)

conf3 = Configuration(
  foo="bar"
)
```

I'd like to detect that `conf1.foo` is using the default value and `conf2.foo` & `conf3.foo` were explicitly set.

Comment: Do you control the Class definition? Can you provide a [mcve]? I'd guess that without a mechanism in the Class to *capture* attribute assignments beyond the initial default assignment that this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: I've added a simple example. I hope it helps.

Comment: And yes, I control all the classes. I had hoped there'd be a built-in way to do this. I'm not a Python expert and the data classes are very elegant and easy to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a start, something like this `merge` function is probably what you could write given your knowledge about `fields`, with the example of instance `z` showing its shortcomings. But given that this implementation uses the `dataclass` tools exactly in the way that they are intended means that it's rather stable, so if at all possible you'd want to use this:

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass, field, fields, MISSING


@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: float = 5
    c: list = field(default_factory=list)


def merge(base, add_on):
    retain = {}
    for f in fields(base):
        val = getattr(base, f.name)
        if val == f.default:
            continue
        if f.default_factory != MISSING:
            if val == f.default_factory():
                continue
        retain[f.name] = val
    kwargs = {**asdict(add_on), **retain}
    return type(base)(**kwargs)


fill = A('1', 1, [1])

x = A('a')
y = A('a', 2, [3])
z = A('a', 5, [])
print(merge(x, fill))  # good: A(a='a', b=1, c=[1])
print(merge(y, fill))  # good: A(a='a', b=2, c=[3])
print(merge(z, fill))  # bad:  A(a='a', b=1, c=[1])
```

Getting the `z` case right is going to involve *some* kind of hack, I'd personally just decorate the dataclass again:

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass, field, fields


def mergeable(inst):
    old_init = inst.__init__

    def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__customs = {f.name for f, _ in zip(fields(self), args)}
        self.__customs |= kwargs.keys()
        old_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def merge(self, other):
        retain = {n: v for n, v in asdict(self).items() if n in self.__customs}
        kwargs = {**asdict(other), **retain}
        return type(self)(**kwargs)

    inst.__init__ = new_init
    inst.merge = merge
    return inst


@mergeable
@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: float = 5
    c: list = field(default_factory=list)


fill = A('1', 1, [1])

x = A('a')
y = A('a', 2, [3])
z = A('a', 5, [])

print(x.merge(fill))  # good: A(a='a', b=1, c=[1])
print(y.merge(fill))  # good: A(a='a', b=2, c=[3])
print(z.merge(fill))  # good: A(a='a', b=5, c=[])
```

This is very likely to have some hard to guess side-effects though, so use at your own risk.

Comment: btw @LarsFranke, some of the expressions in this code are a bit confusing I guess. Since you said you're not an expert (yet :p), do you want some comments in this answers?

Comment: Thank you! They definitely were but I think I understand the gist of what's happening after doing some research.

Thanks for putting in the time.
I learned a lot about Python trying to figure this out.

Regarding your `z` use-case there's an argument to be made that your original one is actually _good_ instead of bad. Because when I decide to explicitly provide an empty list then that might be my intention.

I learned that there's no way (I know of) to distinguish "default" values from manually set ones. I assume this happens at a very low level.

Comment: The level where it happens is actually not that deep at all. python exposes quite a bit of it's own implementation to the user through dunder methods. For this case, another way to solve the question "when and how exactly are my object's arguments being set?" would have been to hack the dataclass' [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) function, which is used to assign `foo` to `self.foo` in the constructor.

Comment: What I meant (and I understand that this would be a totally separate question) is that `__setitem__` will be called with a value. But I do not know where this value comes from, or do I?

I assume that the mechanics in Python resolving function calls (which I understand a dataclass boils down to -> `init` with default values) look at the actual function call and then fill in the blank with default values. `__setitem__` doesn't know wheter it was "Python" or the user who set these values, right?

Comment: whoops, I meant [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) not `__setitem__`. And I think you're right, that approach might not have worked after all. There is now way to know a value's origin, so inspecting the constructor call parameters as i did in my second implementation might be the only way to get it done.

Comment: I guess you are right. I believe your merge function is the closest one can get at the moment. I'm going to accept it.